# JavaScript debugging in FireFox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

In Internet explorer, when there's a JavaScript error, I get a little popup that tells me so. This doesn't happen in FireFox 3. How do I enable this in FF?

I realize this isn't a programming question per se (please don't close this question; forgive me!), but I'm trying to debug some JavaScript and it'd be really nice to see these messages.

I have FireBug enabled if that makes a difference. (Nothing comes up in Firebug either.)

Answer (score 6):

Although you have Firebug, you probably don't have it correctly enabled. Right click the bug icon and select *Enable all panels* and *On for all websites*.

You may also try the *Error console* which lies under the *Tools* menu.

Answer (score 2):

Under the "Tools" Menu and select "Error Console" - hope that helps

Comment: Here's an addon that will let you dock the error console: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9223.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your code does something that doesn't throw an error in Firefox (like string[indexing])

Answer (score 0):

FireBug won't pop up when there's an error, either. Instead, it'll show up in the Console tab assuming it is enabled in the way described by Miguel earlier.